# Cannot access Exchange from guest WiFi

Tags: firewall, exchange-2013

I'm having trouble getting users to be able to connect to Exchange from their cell phones on our wireless. If accessed from completely outside the network, ie from home, then OWA and phone apps sync just fine. Trying to access Exchange or OWA from the WiFi, you get a 502 Bad Gateway. This wireless is completely isolated from the internal network, and uses Google for DNS. The traffic goes out through the firewall, and returns through the same firewall.

Analyzing traffic, I can see requests go out through the firewall, and I can see them come back in and hit the spam appliance. After that, the trail goes dead and I can't figure out where the disconnect is. Ping and tracert both work to the server as well.

We have another WiFi network that has access to the internal network, and that one works fine. I assume it is because it can go directly to the Exchange server.

Comment: `1.` Why are your Exchange users on an isolated wireless network? `2.` Why are Outlook client connections going to your spam appliance?

Comment: This is a BYOD wireless network for their cell phones. The spam appliance NATs the Exchange server, and passes the client connections through while actively scanning any emails that come in.

Comment: I'm not clear why the connection goes through SPAM appliance. The access of the devices is done through HTTPS to the ActiveSync vdir on the Exchange CAS. Please elaborate.